# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sangamApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I want to display a calendar on my webpage , the below code works fine if i dont put ['ui.calendar'] in angular.module(), but in that case , the calendar is not being displayed , and if i add that to angular.module() , it is showing the above error . please help me !

these are my two javascript files

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('sangamApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider',function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('calendar', {
        url: '/calendar',
        template: '<calendar></calendar>'
      });
  }]);
```

```js
'use strict';
(function(){

class CalendarComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.eventSources = [];
    
    this.uiConfig = {
       calendar : {
              editable : true,
              header : {
                        left : 'prev,next,today',
                        centre : 'title',
                        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                       }
                  }
                }
  }
}

angular.module('sangamApp',['ui.calendar'])
  .component('calendar', {
    templateUrl: 'app/calendar/calendar.html',
    controller: CalendarComponent
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `$stateProvider` but you forgot to put `ui.router` in your module dependencies.

```
angular.module('sangamApp',['ui.calendar', 'ui.router']) // added ui.router
```

Comment: but it was working fine , when i didn't put 'ui.calendar' as well as 'ui.router' ....and its not working even if i add 'ui.router'

Comment: That's strange. Is the first javascript file your main js file? Also which one of the file is loaded first?

Answer (score 0):

The **first time** you declare the app module you need to pass list of all the module dependencies as the second parameter to `angular.module` and since you are using `$stateProvider` you should specify the `ui.router` in the list of dependecies

```
angular.module('sangamApp',['ui.calendar', 'ui.router'])
```